# How can I base64 encode using Fable (F#)?

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I use FetchAPI of Fable.PowerPack to make basic authentication application, but I am in trouble because I can not base64 encode.

For example, I wrote such a code,

```
let base64enc str =
    str
    |> Seq.map byte
    |> Array.ofSeq
    |> System.Convert.ToBase64String
```

However, the following error occurs.

`Error FABLE: Can not find replacement for System.Convert.ToBase64String`

Is there any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the JavaScript [`btoa` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) does what you need. The easiest and quickest way to make it available in Fable is to use the `Emit` attribute:

```
[<Emit("btoa($0)")>]
let toBase64String (bytes:byte[]) : string = failwith "JS"
```

There might be some slight differences between the .NET method and the JS function, in which case you'll probably need to reimplement those on your own.

Also, this sounds like a thing that Fable could support - the replacements for .NET operations are generally defined in the [Replacements.fs file](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/blob/master/src/dotnet/Fable.Compiler/Replacements.fs) and if you were interested in sending a pull request to add mapping for `ToBase64String` and others, that would be amazing!

Comment: [<Emit("btoa($0)")>]
let toBase64String (bytes:byte[]) : string = failwith "JS"

Comment: @KenjiTokudome You are right - off by one error :-) Fixed it now.

Comment: There are only two hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors. :-)